# How to read a pixel? And how pixel coordinates work on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

How do you read a pixel from the screen? How do you get the color of the pixel from entering coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

function for this:

```
- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point {
UIColor* color = nil;
CGImageRef inImage = self.image.CGImage;
// Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 

// Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
// allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
// raw image data in the specified color space.
CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage); 

// Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
// context.
unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
if (data != NULL) {
    //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
    //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
    int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
    int alpha =  data[offset];
    int red = data[offset+1];
    int green = data[offset+2];
    int blue = data[offset+3];
    NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);
    color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
}

// When finished, release the context
CGContextRelease(cgctx);
// Free image data memory for the context
if (data) { free(data); }

return color;
```

}

For more info see [HERE](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/)
Also here is the GitHub [LINK](https://github.com/achievelimitless/SharedRepository/tree/master/ColorPicker)

Hope this helps you a lot.